# Difference between get_Offset and Offset?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I do not understand the difference between `get_Offset` and `Offset`:

[MSDN on NamedRange.get_Offset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.get_offset.aspx) states

> This API supports the Visual Studio infrastructure and is not intended
>   to be used directly from your code. Use the Offset property instead of
>   this method.

What does that mean exactly? Similar is also said for [get_Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.get_value%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method which is widely used directly in code.

Take following examples which would do the same for me.

```
myRange.get_Offset(1,0).Value = "Foo";
myRange.Offset[1,0].Value = "Foo";
```

What are their difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
get_Something
```

is an internal function that generates by the CLR for property `get` accessor.

For example if you have a property

```
public string Name {get;set;}
```

after compilation you will find a

`get_Name` and `set_Name` *methods*, cause the properties are nothing then simple *wrappers* over the set-variable/get-variable concept in a single class domain.

**Being an internal method, it's not good practise to make use of it, it's better to use a user defined, clear `property` access.**

Comment: @SidHolland: no, it's just a property semantic construct, I don't believe it has any relation with internal implementation of it in compiler. Methods has (, properties *can* have [. To make a clear difference in code, when you see a.Name() or a.Name[] (which can be a pulic collection field too naturally)

Comment: Thanks. I deleted my comment because as soon as I'd posted it I thought it sounded absurd, but perhaps it wasn't. For the benefit of those who read the above comment and are confused, here it is (approximately) again: So is that difference between `[]` and `()`, that the former contains indexes for a property and the latter parameters for a method?

Answer (score 1):

get_Offset can theoretically be changed or removed without warning. If the documentation says to use another equivalent method you should do just that.
get_Value is only marked that way for Visual Studio 2005 so you can use that freely

Answer (score 0):

The difference is exactly as the documentation says. You should use the `Offset` property, not the `get_Offset` method.

The method is just public because they needed it to be accessible in that way for some other class. The method may just go away in any future version if they find a better way to use the class, and it won't even be mentioned as a breaking change as the documentation clearly states that you shouldn't use it.